# How to write url in xlsxwriter that changes color when clicked

Tags: url, colors, xlsxwriter

I know xlsxwriter has a write_url function, and I know about setting formats and how to make the text of that url blue. In this case my urls point to other cells in the same spreadsheet. However, I'm wondering if xlsxwriter has a way to set the color of the url such that it will change color once it's been clicked, like the usual blue when unclicked and purple when clicked, for example like Google does with search results you have previously visited.

I know openpyxl has a way to do this, with the builtin 'Hyperlink' style or creating a Color object with theme=10. Is there a way to do this in xlsxwriter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to do this in xlsxwriter?

Not currently. If you open a feature request I can look at adding it.